# Converting varchar to decimal in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have this data as varchar '00072330'. How do I convert it to a decimal that looks like '723.30' in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @data as varchar(8)
set @data = '00072330'
print cast(@data as decimal) / 100
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
SELECT CAST('00072330' AS INT)/100.0
```

...will give you:

> 723.300000

The .0 is important, otherwise SQL Server will perform integer math.

Comment: .0 is required because you casted to int; casting to decimal don't requires it

Comment: Yes, but why not be more explicit when you cast as decimal?  If you know you are limited to 8 characters (two decimal places) I would much rather see AS DECIMAL(8,2) than just AS DECIMAL.  YMMV.

Comment: I think the point of the conversion is because the precision is not consistent.  But you make a good point about setting the precision on the cast/convert.  I'm still not up to speed on my SQL Server datatypes.