# How can I remove trailing and leading zeroes then convert to a decimal without rounding

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I convert 000000000000000001764705 to 1.76?

Comment: how do you know where the decimal place goes? why is that 1.76 and not 17.64705?

Comment: Tons of ways to do it ? In C, Java ?? What is the logic to put decimal ?

Comment: You can do it with the power of PATINDEX and SUBSTRING.

Comment: The decimal will always be 6 positions from the right.

Comment: You can use cast as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589707/converting-varchar-to-decimal-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do it...

```
select reverse(round(reverse(round(cast(000000000000000001764705 as decimal)/1000000,2)),1))
```

let me explain: First when you convert it to any decimal or numeric all the leading zero's will truncate as in numeric cases leading zero have no value. second we divided it by 1000000 because as mentioned by user2618885 the decimal will always be 6 positions from the right and then we rounded it up to 2 place after decimal but it will not truncate it to 2 place after decimal instead it will put only the trailing zero's after 2 places of decimal like "1.76000000". third trying to remove the zero's after 2 decimal places by reversing it and then rounding it and again reversing it to original position which can be done in another ways also by using substring, stuff etc... but i used here reverse and round.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of JLampon's comment link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589707/converting-varchar-to-decimal-in-sql-server-2008):

```
declare @data as varchar(24)
set @data = '000000000000000001764705'
print round(cast(@data as float) / 1000000,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF` to insert the decimal at required position. Then `CAST` to convert it to decimal.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @number VARCHAR(255) = '000000000000000001764705'

SELECT CAST(STUFF(@number, len(@number)-5, 0, '.') as DECIMAL(18,2))


/*
RESULT

---------------------------------------
1.76

(1 row(s) affected)

*/
```